# output buffering with database calls?

Tags: php

In file1.php I have

```
include 'database_functions.php';

// bunch of other stuff

function render_php($path){
    ob_start();
    include($path);
    $var=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $var;
}
echo render_php('file2.php');
```

Then in file2.php I have:

```
include 'database_functions.php';
$stmt = $db->prepare(" // do stuff ");
....
```

The problem I am having is if I add database_functions.php to file2 I get an error and if I don't add database_functions.php to file2 I also get an error.

Without the database_functions.php in file2 I get:

```
Undefined variable: db
```

With the database_functions.php in file2 I get:

```
Constant DBHOST already defined
```

So the obvious question is how would I render file2.php without getting errors. (include/require will not work in this situation).

Comment: `include_once` and `require_once` was made for the particular purpose of only loading a file once no matter how many times you try to load it.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I have also tried using include_once in the render_php() function as well as in the file2.php when calling database_functions and it also returns Undefined variable: db

Comment: `$db` is undefined, because its not available inside your function. You need to pass it to the function as argument or make it a global variable. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php to learn about scope in php

Comment: Start using functions, classes, and explicitly passed function parameters. You’re in this mess because you’re using plain, globally scoped, implicitly expected, auto-executing-on-include code.

Comment: Deceze that was my plan was to try rewriting the globally scoped if I could find no other answer, however simon.ro's answer is so much easier :) Just pass the $db to function. :) Thanks guys. Got it sorted. Sometimes its the little things that get overlooked ;)